Above the ship ground, what is this layer of blue hue?
In the latest Alien: Romulus (2024), when Andy the Android notices there is a layer of blue hue just above the ground in a section of an abandoned space station, he reaches down and tries to touch it.
What is this layer of blue hue? What is its purpose?


https://filmstories.co.uk/features/alien-romulus-and-the-45-year-mystery-of-the-blue-mist/

With both its presence in the original film and apparently its unexplained presence in Romulus, it seems whatever it means is still up for grabs, especially judging by current net chatter. I'm of the 'warning' proximity layer suggested for the original film, where it gave an audible shift when broken. Kind of a dangerous cargo alarm.
